# Calling another VI at runtime

Tags: labview

I have created two vi's in LabVIEW: one to acquire serial data and another to plot the acquired data on an XY graph.

The second VI gets called when a Value Change event occurs on a button in the first VI. But the problem is that when the second VI is called the first VI suspends its operation, hence the values don't get updated.

Is there any solution for this?

First VI block diagram:

[image: first VI block diagram]

First VI front panel:

[image: first VI front panel]

Second VI (ALL DATA) block diagram:

[image: ALL DATA block diagram]

Comment: Please can you also show us the ALL DATA VI? Or at least tell us whether this VI is supposed to show a static snapshot of the acquired data at the point the button was clicked, or a graph that continues to update as new data is acquired?

Comment: All DATA vi is used to update xy graph continuously based on acquired data. it just use global variables values as input to xy graph

Comment: You should divide out the DAQ task from the GUI update task. That is, they should be in separate loops. I'd recommend using DVRs for large DAQ tasks, as they are about the most efficient way to store data in memory in LabVIEW.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are doing some nasty stuff with global variables. This works but is not considered as good practice. (Have a look at *queues* and *notifiers*). Further, I don't see how your data gets written to those variables...

In any case, put your 2nd VI in a separate while-loop and schedule it to about 100ms (that is usually enough to update front panels or to interact with users. I'm not sure if your button-event is the right way to go. That is exactly because, the second VI waits for the callback. **Just use a simple button and a true-false case to let the second VI keep running** (this should even be the solution if you don't want to move the case to a second VI). Just make sure that you change the mechanics of the button to be a switch because you're checking its value not at infinite speed and you want to ensure that it gets caught every time, you click it;)

Comment: i tried using queue and separate loop for second vi now my first vi is not hang but the second vi is not updating its data.     https://ibb.co/rdhjFqV

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the VI Server functionality.  The exact method has changed over the years, but I believe the current recommended implementation is to use 'Start Asynchronous Call'

There is an example that you can view using the example finder.  To open the example finder navigate to Help>Find Examples.  Then select the 'Search' tab and search for 'asynchronous'.  Finally select the VI called 'Asynchronous Call and Forget.vi'

There are other variations for asynchronous implementations, but this is probably a good place to start.